# Guest session stopped working on Ubuntu versions later than 16.04

Tags: lightdm, guest-session

After a recent package update, the guest session feature is no longer available on Ubuntu 16.10 and 17.04. What happened?

Comment: if that applies like that to 18.04 can we add tags to that version please.

Comment: @TiloBunt: Thanks for pointing it out. It does apply to all versions later than 16.04 which use LightDM, so I dropped the version tags instead and changed the title. Default display manager for standard Ubuntu as from 17.10 is GDM, which does not carry a guest session feature at all.

Comment: Related: [How to enable guest sessions on Ubuntu 18.04 or later?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112349/how-to-enable-guest-sessions-on-ubuntu-18-04-or-later)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The guest session was [intentionally disabled by default](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1663157) due to a security issue, where the guest session was not contained by the AppArmor profile that usually limits guest sessions. This AppArmor profile, among other things, prevents a guest user from using `su` to switch to other users, or viewing other users' home directories.

You can enable it, if you consider the issue to be manageable on your system, as explained in [comment #24 of the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1663157/comments/24) or by using this one liner:

```
sudo sh -c 'printf "[Seat:*]\nallow-guest=true\n" >/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/40-enable-guest.conf'
```

To reverse it back to the disabled state, simply do:

```
sudo rm /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/40-enable-guest.conf
```

Comment: Is 16.04 unaffected by this?

Comment: @Anwar: No it's not. It's a systemd thing.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson A systemd thing? So, everything since 15.04? Or is it due to the switch from upstart to systemd for user session inits?

Comment: @Anwar: The latter (I think - please see the bug report).

Comment: @muru ^ I think Gunnar meant you

Comment: @Anwar: I did, of course. Thanks for heads up.

Comment: @muru: Thanks for the edit, but I removed the `su` part since it reasonably not applies (guests are not included in `/etc/sudoers`).

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson It's not a big deal, but a) `su` doesn't use `sudoers`, and b) AppArmor apparently prevents `su` and `sudo` from functioning properly for guests (so `sudoers` doesn't even enter the picture). A user would need to know a valid user's password, but on an otherwise locked down system without access to TTYs, it does open a hole.

Comment: @muru: Hmm.. I thought that `su` couldn't be used without `sudo`, but apparently it can. I retract (just edited back). Thanks for the lesson!

Comment: But is there a problem, if other user's home directory is encrypted? What could guest user do by `su`?

Comment: @jarno: Good question. I'm not able to tell offhand.

Comment: One problem is that the home directory that uses ecryptfs does not encrypt again even on logout, see [LP: 1734541](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1734541). Anyway, it seems that Xubuntu 18.04 does not suffer from the guest session security issue; see [the continuation bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1742912)

Comment: So someone would have to have my password to cause any damage?

Comment: @OlliverK: To use `su`: yes, to view your home directory: no.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I don't really keep anything on my internal hard drive, so I'm not worried about that.  Thanks for the information.

Comment: @muru can you explain how does it open a hole? Do you mean someone can try to log in to your system via network by using guest session or what?

Comment: @jarno I mean if there's a set up where your average user is only intended to use the guest session (e.g., a kiost at a mall or a library or something), then allowing them to be able to `su` to another user would be a security hole.

Comment: @muru oh, I have to try it. Though currently I am unable to exit my guest session due to some bug kinds of which have been around for several years :(