# start a guest session in Ubuntu 17.10 / cinnamon

Tags: cinnamon, 17.10, guest-session

In Ubuntu 16.10 with Unity I could launch a guest session as follows:

[image]

Now I use Ubuntu 17.10  with cinnamon. The correspoding menu looks like
 [image]

and does not allow me to start a guest session.
Also I did not find the functionality anywhere else.
Is it still there? How do I start it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guest session feature may be available from the login screen if you use the LightDM display manager. However, [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/915415) is still present, and you'll need to consider that security issue before enabling guest session.

Comment: my personal takeaway: the guest session feature has been removed from ubuntu 16.10+ because of a security issue and it is unclear if/when it will come back officially :( -- the details and a workaround to re-enable it unsecured are in https://launchpad.net/bugs/1663157

Comment: There is nothing as login as guest on my login screen...I am from installing ubuntu 17.10 without changing any default software(login,file manager...)...

Comment: @aidonsnous: Standard ubuntu 17.10 uses the GDM display manager by default, not LightDM.