# How to disable guest session or login in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, guest-session

In Ubuntu 17.10, the LightDM method to disable guest session or login does not work anymore.

Is there any new method?

Comment: There's a guest session available in 17.10? I thought GDM wouldn't even support it until 18.04, and it was disabled in LightDM anyway due to apparmor problems (https://askubuntu.com/a/915417/158442)

Comment: @muru: GDM [won't support it in 18.04 either](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/brain-dump-on-guest-session-progress/3717).

Comment: It still has a login in when switch the user list to guest, but not know the pw this time.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the user list? And the output of `id` if you switch to this guest user?