# How to create Guest Session in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10

I have to share my pc with unknown people , and  I recently upgraded my ubuntu os to 17.10 version in which guest session is missing . Is there an option to re-enable the guest session or I need to do something else ?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/915415/guest-session-stopped-working-on-ubuntu-16-10-and-17-04

Comment: @Panther The question you linked seems to be about LightDM whereas 17.10 uses GDM by default. Will the answer(s) apply?

Comment: @pomsky - It is not a direct answer, so I did not mark it as a dup. However it links to the bug report - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1663157 . I do not think the guest session is available, but I do not know.

Comment: @Panther If you are not sure and if you don't know then please don't confuse me .

Comment: @Panther My question is very clear . First  try the solution for problem by yourself and then answer my question .