# Is there any way to set up Guest account in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Running a community IT room where various people can use the pc's and want to ensure that the system is safe and also that a standard startup is presented.
There used to be a guest user ability in earlier versions of Ubuntu but since updating all the hardware to Ubuntu 18.04 we are unable to discover how to set up guest user accounts.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: its possible by installing lightdm.. this is a duplicate question.. i am checking that link..

Comment: Follow the accepted answer on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089953/guest-on-ubuntu-18-04