# How to enable guest account on Lubuntu 18.10 [SDDM]

Tags: lubuntu, 18.10, guest-session, sddm, lxqt

It has been a default setting on most of Ubuntu flavors and it's fairly easy to do on LightDM, but I wonder if SDDM also has this option.

If not, is it worth to completely purge SDDM in favour of LightDM just for this option?

Comment: https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues/1091 It doesn't look like anybody has taken to it yet :/

Comment: It's really up to you to decide how important you think the guest session feature is. But please note that the guest session in LightDM does currently not offer the original security level: https://askubuntu.com/q/915415