# How to enable guest sessions on Ubuntu 18.04 or later?

Tags: gnome, guest-session

Is there any way you could revive Guest Sessions in a future LTS distro?  Guest sessions are good security - they give me just enough power to do what I need to do on a daily basis without risking my system. In short, Guest sessions save me from myself.  I had upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04, gotten a problem I couldn't fix and was all to happy to wipe and rebuild my hard drive and return to 16.04.  I can't be the only one who feels this way.

Comment: Related: [Guest session stopped working on Ubuntu versions later than 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915415/guest-session-stopped-working-on-ubuntu-versions-later-than-16-04)

Answer (score 15):

> Is there any way you could revive Guest Sessions in a future LTS distro?

You seem to believe we can get this back into a distribution but we are just users (except for a couple of people that are also employees of Canonical).

And if you want it back: install LightDM.

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

Create a configuration file

```
sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-enable-guest.conf
```

and copy the contents below to it:

```
[Seat:*]
allow-guest=true
```

Reboot the computer and pick lightdm at the login screen.

Do read the [wiki page CustomizeGuestSession](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession) and [the discussion on removing guest accounts](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/guest-sessions-in-18-04-lts-are-they-needed/1714).

Before you start using it: **Guest Account is NOT secure**: the data from normal users on the system is not secure from the guest. The same goes for the data from the guest. And the guest can view system files.