# Is there a deep freeze type of software for newer versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: scripts, software-recommendation, user-data

I am trying to figure out how to go about having a user log into a Ubuntu machine, use it to their heart's content, and when they log off delete all of the user data from that account. All of the stuff I have found thus far is about deleting an account instead of just the data. Any help would be a Godsend. Thanks

Comment: This sounds pretty much like the guest session.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto That sounds like the best bet--do you want to post an answer? We have [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112349/how-to-enable-guest-sessions-on-ubuntu-18-04-or-later) and [Guest session stopped working on Ubuntu versions later than 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/915415/22949) but they don't really explain what the guest session is or most of the important considerations in deciding whether to use it. And there may be other ways to achieve this, so I'm thinking this shouldn't really be closed as a duplicate of anything that's *just* about guest sessions.

Comment: @EliahKagan gosh, I haven't actually used it in a very long time and didn't realize it is now disabled. :D

Comment: @oddball87 I see this has been closed as a duplicate of the related question about guest sessions. If [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112349/how-to-enable-guest-sessions-on-ubuntu-18-04-or-later) doesn't provide the kind of solution you're looking for, you can **[edit]** this question to explain why; your edit will automatically cause it to be reviewed for possible reopening. (If that does work for you, great! This can remain closed as a duplicate and help people searching the web make their way to that question.)