# Adding new standard user

Tags: 18.04, user-management

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I want also to allow to use my PC my brother.

It would not be a problem if it had a guest account but since 18.04 has no guest account I am wondering what data is accesable through a normal user account.

Would it be possible for my brother to change something in the system? Can he access WLAN password or similar data?

I would like to „trust my PC“ after he has used it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A command to list all users? And how to add, delete, modify users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410244/a-command-to-list-all-users-and-how-to-add-delete-modify-users)

Comment: You can have a guest account: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112349/how-to-enable-guest-sessions-on-ubuntu-18-04-or-later

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "Standard" account (from Settings -> Detail -> Users -> Add user).

Standard users can use software like Firefox, IDE, a music player, or download files, read their own. They can also change settings that only affects themselves, such as his wallpaper.

Standard users cannot install/upgrade/uninstall software or change system-wide settings, e.g. WLAN password. 
Standard user can read/copy documents and photos in your Home directory and any file or created elsewhere but not able to modify/delete them.

Comment: With default permissions any user would have read-access to the files in your home-directory and you'd have to modify the permissions of your home-folder to prevent this. The last sentence in your answer is not correct.

Comment: That means that the Standard user can read my files even if I have a Administrator account?  But he cannot access the system files and connot do any changes to system or turn off the antivirus (Sophos free for Linux) or change the firewall settings?

Comment: @BarbaraMa, Yes, but you can change file permission to block access from other users. (Right click your file, choose **property**, in the  **permission** tab change access of others from "Read-only" to "None".

Comment: @BarbaraMa Only admins can change status/settings of a modern anti-virus/firewall. The only things to do is to protect your private file. As mook765 said, Linux by default grant read access  of most files to all users.