# login and guest session

Tags: login, guest-session, accounts

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I have an issue where I can't log in to the guest session, and it does not even appear after booting into my machine. clicking on "switch accounts" does nothing. And when I log out of the local account, I get a log in screen written Debian8. how can I fix this

Comment: Here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112349/how-to-enable-guest-sessions-on-ubuntu-18-04-or-later is how to enable guest sessions in 18.04. It is a lightdm (the login manager) configuration, so you may use these instructions to check your system. First check whether you use lightdm, the default display manager in 16.04. If yes, then check the lightdm configuration files as in the linked post.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  I still get the same welcome screen after booting my system. and I still can't log in to guest session or add accounts.

Comment: Unless you use Unity, you are not supposed to be able to log in to the guest session from within a user session. But it ought to be an option on the login screen. Which desktop environment are you on?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what a Desktop environment is, but I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on a Acer Aspire laptop.

Comment: @DyrexionCarter: I meant Unity, Xubuntu, GNOME, etc. Or are you simply on standard Ubuntu (with Unity)?

Comment: Yes I'm on standard Ubuntu