# Setting readonly on a USB stick

Tags: usb, read-only, hdparm

I want to create a USB stick with a tool to scan for viruses. I installed the software and after that I set:

```
hdparm -r1 /dev/sdc1
```

When I check the USB stick I get this:

```
hdparm -r /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdc1: readonly = 1 (on)
```

When I unplug the USB stick and plug it back in I get this:

```
hdparm -r /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdc1: readonly = 0 (off)
```

The write protection seems not to be not working.

How can I make the setting persistent?

Comment: You can install a Guest User: https://askubuntu.com/a/1223764/43926. This allows the Admin user to modify the OS but prevents the Guest from modifying it. I have seen another method to add a Guest User: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/07/create-guest-account-ubuntu-20-04/ , but have not tried it yet.