# Ever clean ubuntu start

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, configuration, live-cd, livedvd

I want to install a ubuntu SO on some laptops. This laptops will be used for studens between 12-16 years old, so to avoid problems I would like to start the ubuntu every time from a clear .iso (like in a USB live). In other words thats it that everithing that the studens do won't be saved in the machine. At the same time I need to save some configurations and add some repositoris for the use in this iso (wifi configuration, some programs...). Someone knows if that is possible?

Thankyou

Comment: You can store an ISO on a internal drive just like it was an external thumb-drive or CD; then on turning the device on it'll boot the ISO from the actual physical disk, however the type of file that is booted is RO with changes saved as COW/copy-on-write (in RAM) meaning nothing on disk is changed. You can even have multiple type ISOs on the disk & have `grub` boot and used to select which you'll boot & use.  You've provided no specific architecture/OS/release details, and I'm unsure what you mean by Ubuntu SO?  (*did you mean OS*?)

Comment: The standard way would be to create non-admin accounts for the students. The students would be able to save files in their home folder, but won't be able to modify the system or install anything.

Comment: There's also `overlayroot`, so user changes from your customized base system can be easily deleted anytime without needing to re-image.

Comment: I wonder if this is an [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The *real* problem seems to be easy fleet management and security with untrusted users. There are lots of possible solutions to that, among which "start with a clear .iso" is one alternative.

Comment: A **Guest Account** may be what you want, you can put it on USB. https://askubuntu.com/a/1223764/43926