How to restore everything to a default profile after every reboot or logout?
I would like to use Ubuntu in my school. But I have a couple of questions about how to make certain configurations.
I have seen in Windows a program that allows you to reset the user account every time the computer is restarted. The program in Windows is called "Deep Freeze". It would be nice if there was an option that allows this for the education part.
On the other hand and related to the above, would it be possible to block the change of settings, wallpaper?

This seems to be a use case for the Guest Session, which resets for every use. The reset includes settings. On a stock install of Ubuntu (newer than 16.04), the Guest Session is disabled, but can be enabled. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/915415/ for additional information about how to enable it.

Please update your question and explain what you mean explicitly. I took your question to mean that you want your user session restored to exactly what it was when you logged off; @user535733 understood it to mean the exact opposite. Which do you want?

Does this answer your question? Guest session stopped working on Ubuntu versions later than 16.04

See this article
